# How to implement Multi-step ahead regression with LSTM in Keras?

Tags: python, time-series, keras, lstm, multi-step

I'm new to Keras . I want to predict the next 30 values of a time series using the previous 10 values of features (5 different features). Here is my code but I am almost sure that it is not the right way to do that. any idea?

```py
# features is a (11277,10,5) array--> (samples, time steps, features)
# predictions is a (11277,30) array--> (samples, outputs)
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(features.shape[1], features.shape[2]),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(300, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(predictions.shape[1], init='uniform', activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam")
```

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: RNN use `y_(t+1) = f(W*x_t + U*h_t)`, you are only supplying `h_t`. If you can answer what your `x_t` will be in the steps where it is 'not present' then you have answered your question.